SharePoint Rich Text Column - Power Automate Document Generation flow
I have built a Power Automate flow that populates a Word document with data submitted in a SharePoint Online list.  This all works well, except in that SharePoint list I have two Enhanced Rich Text columns, which populate the word document with a bunch of "DIVs ExternalClass", etc.  I can't change the two SharePoint columns to Plain text (it's not my list).  So I'm trying to figure out how I can get these two columns to display as plain text in my document.  First, is there a way I can set a calculated column to convert the Rich Text column value to plain text?  If not, how would I accomplish this in the flow?
Thank you!

I haven't used it yet but there is a "HTML to Text" connector for Power Automate. It is currently in preview but maybe worth looking into. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/conversionservice/

User Html to text to convert your html value of Enhanced rich text content to plain text from Power Automate flow.


This connector is in preview version so can't be used in production apps. Please suggest some alternative solution.
